# SSRS referring to Database Project in the solution

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SSRS reports project and a database project in the same SSDT solution. The reports use a shared data source (the same database as the database project) and stored procedures from the database for their main data sets.
I noticed that one of the reports wasn't building due to errors in the stored procedure.

It turned out that the SSRS project was looking at the version of the stored procedure in the database project rather than the actual database, to see if the stored procedure was correct.

Has anyone encountered this, and where is the configuration within the solution to tell SSRS to use the database project rather than the 'real' data source?

Answer (score -1):

SSRS will not looking for schema in a database project. This is not an option that I am aware of. If possible, you can create a temp SP to use for testing purposes and then switch prior to deployment.

Comment: It definitely was doing this, and I thought it odd, hence the question.

Comment: Perhaps you were using a cached version. In VS, a SSRS project will cache the data. You either have to refresh that dataset or hit the green data refresh button on the report  viewer to go back to the DB. If you change a SP and don't refresh your VS project will still use a cached version. You need to refresh probally.

Comment: Yeah I know about that- in design mode, refreshing the dataset did what I'd expect, and in preview mode it wouldn't compile. It gave errors in the SP. It linked to the database project's version of the stored proc which exhibited those errors. Its bizarre behaviour, so I hope someone has seen this before or can explain why it might have happened.